# What does piercing damage do in Darksiders 2?

Tags: xbox-360, darksiders-2

Ok, so i am  building a Possessed Weapon in Darksiders 2, I am playing on Apocolyptic, and I wanna build the best possessed weapon i can. So it is between piercing damage and elemental damage. My question is basically, what does piercing damage do, and is it more beneficial than elemental damage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piercing damage is used to negate armor on enemies so it is particularly strong on any high armor targets but on enemies with no armor it seems like a waste. Elemental damage has different effect for each element. Overall I think elemental damage is more useful than piercing. Ice seems to be a strong choice.

Here are a list of elemental damages in Darksiders 2 found [here](http://www.ign.com/wikis/darksiders-2/Combat).

*Arcane*:
This is the type of damage which is inflicted by Death in his Reaper form. There are also attack combos that will allow Death to inflict extra Arcane damage by briefly unleashing his Reaper Form.

*Fire*:
This damage type will set enemies ablaze, dealing extra damage and steady, continuous damage over time.

*Inferno*:
Burn effect on the enemies you struck, spreads to nearby enemies with splash damage effect. A Stronger version of fire.

*Frost*:
This damage type will inflict freezing damage and will slow them down, making it easier to avoid their attacks and land counterattacks.

*Ice*:
Chance to totally freeze enemies(except Bosses) for few seconds and will also slow them down. A Stronger version of frost.

*Shock*:
Causes small flickering lightning damage on strike.

*Lightning*:
A little longer flickering lightning damage effect which inflicts damage overtime  and has a chance to stun enemies, leaving them vulnerable for 2/3 seconds.